# What is the URL parameter ?fireglass_rsn=true

Tags: url

I'm getting traffic to my website containing the URL in the structure:

//domain/pagename/?fireglass_rsn=true

Anyone know what the ?fireglass_rsn parameter is doing?

See the screenshot from Google Analytics. These 2 pages are actually the same page. The fireglass_rsn visits are all from Singapore, which is weird as well.

[image]

Comment: That depends on the server responding to that request. Can give us more details?

Comment: I've given a screenshot from Google Analytics. It's a page on the blog of my site. None of the other pages / blog posts have ever had this behaviour and this post also hasn't before yesterday. The post was first published a few years ago.

Comment: I'm seeing the same parameter on my website. It's not caused by the server. My best guess is that it's coming from some kind of firewall on the client side. There seems to be a product called Fireglass Threat Isolation. I never heard of it before but wouldn't be surprised if it's responsible.

Comment: @FlorianSander. It's what my company uses. Big PITA for user, probably not a problem for you.

Comment: Have you found out why?. My Analytics have started show them randomly in some page since last 7 days

Comment: yup, I encountered that recently as well.